# Users can read collection when no access is specified

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I set up my firebase DB rules like this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    // ********** PRIVATE DATA **********
    match /ContactInfo/{uid} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
    match /MyInterests/{uid} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
    match /Subscriptions/{uid} {
    allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
    match /UserData/{uid} {
        allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
    // ********** PUBLIC DATA **********
    match /Interests {
        allow read;
    }
  }
}
```

(Thanks Doug Stevenson for your YouTube videos)

I have a folder collection named 'Blogs' that users can read event though I did not specify access above. Since they can access data that is supposed to have an implicit deny, I question the security of the rest of my data...What am I doing wrong?
[image]

[image]

Here's the code:

```
import 'package:TeamSolheim/home.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class BlogPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  BlogPageState createState() {
    return BlogPageState();
  }
}

class BlogPageState extends State<BlogPage> {
  String id;
  final db = Firestore.instance;
  String name;
  static String url = '';

  Card buildItem(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return Card(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 60.0, width: 500.0,
              child: RaisedButton(
                color: Home.buttonBG,
                onPressed: () async {
                  url = '${doc.data['blogLink']}';
                  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
                    await launch(url);
                  } else {
                    throw 'Could not launch $url';
                  }
                  print(doc.data['blogLikes']);
                  updateData(doc);
                  print(doc.data['blogLikes']);
                  setState(() {});
                },
                child: AutoSizeText(
                  '${doc.data['blogTitle']}',
                  maxLines: 1,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 24,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  flex: 5,
                  child: Text(
                    'Likes: ${doc.data['blogLikes']}',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(flex: 4,child: SizedBox(width: 100.0)),
                Expanded(
                  flex: 10,
                  child: Text(
                    'Date: ${doc.data['blogDate']}',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('${Home.title}'),
          backgroundColor: Home.appbarBG,
          elevation: 0.0,
        ),
      body: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
        children: <Widget>[

          StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
            stream: db.collection('Blogs').snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Column(children: snapshot.data.documents.map((doc) => buildItem(doc)).toList());
              } else {
                return SizedBox();
              }
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void readData() async {
    DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await db.collection('Blogs').document(id).get();
    print(snapshot.data['name']);
  }

  void updateData(DocumentSnapshot doc) async {
//    await db.collection('Blogs').document(doc.documentID).get();
//    print('DB value ${doc.data['blogLikes']}');
    doc.data['blogLikes']++;
    await db.collection('Blogs').document(doc.documentID).updateData({'blogLikes': doc.data['blogLikes']});
  }
}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code of the query that should be denied by the rules.  The rules by themselves don't have any meaning without also seeing the queries they are intended to allow or deny.  We need to be able to see that your code actually matches the rules.

Comment: https://github.com/SSolheim2000/TeamSolheim/blob/master/blog.dart

Comment: The code needs to be in the question itself so it's useful for others in the future, even if your repo changes or goes away.

Comment: I added the code, but it really doesn't make sense that the code would make a difference. I thought the rules were supposed to protect my data??

Comment: Please narrow down the code to show **only** the query that fails. We need to be able to see that the query code and the values you pass to it match the rules exactly.

Comment: My guess is the 'read data()' module at the end of the code. Since I haven't given any permissions to read this container (Blogs) on the database side, how can it read the data within?